# defaultdict automatically creating dictionary entries for keys accessed later on

Tags: python

What does the below sentence mean in the context of `defaultdict`? I know how `defaultdict` works, but I have no idea what is meant by this sentence. Can anyone explain?

> One caution with `defaultdict` is that it will automatically create dictionary entries for defaultdict keys accessed later on (even if they aren’t currently found in the dictionary).

-- From a Python book I'm reading.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
d['a'].append(1)
d['a'].append(2)
d['b'].append(4)
```

One caution with `defaultdict` is that it will automatically create dictionary entries for `defaultdict` keys accessed later on (even if they aren’t currently found in the dictionary). If you don’t
want this behavior, you might use `setdefault` on an ordinary dictionary instead. For example:

```
d = {} # A regular dictionary
d.setdefault('a', []).append(1)
d.setdefault('a', []).append(2)
d.setdefault('b', []).append(4)
```

Comment: It *might* mean that if you try and read the value of a missing key, defaultdict will create the default value, and you might not want it to do that. But it is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other words:

`defaultdict` is useful because it provides a default when the key does not exist. However, this is also a danger because a programming error may go uncaught because of this -- For example, a typo in a key name would otherwise produce a `KeyError` but will not with a `defaultdict`.

```py
# example with dict
mydict = {}
mydict['a'] = list()
mydict['a'].append('foo')

# example with defaultdict
mydefaultdict = defaultdict(list)
mydefultdict['a'].append('foo')


# Now, imagine a typo occurs accessing each example:
# the key 'aa' is mistakenly used instead of 'a'
print(mydefaultdict['aa'])  # no error
print(mydict['aa']) # KeyError is raised
```

So, in this way, defaultdict can produce a hazard where errors like this do not cause the program to stop and can make it difficult to debug because the erroneous access may only produce an error after the unexpected value is passed far later in the program.

The book offers a strange solution to this -- using `setdefault`. While this works, it kind of defeats part of the purpose in why you would use defaultdict to begin with.

The problem described by the book can be avoided in a much simpler way -- by setting `mydefaultdict.default_factory = None` when you no longer want the default dict to produce defaults.

```py
mydefaultdict = defaultdict(dict)
foo['bar']['baz'] = 'bacon'
foo['eggs']['spam'] = 'foo'
mydefaultdict.default_factory = None
# now it behaves like a normal dictionary
foo['eggz'] # KeyError
```

Answer (score 1):

As the caution states, accessing an element outside the context of trying to set a value in a `defaultdict` will create an entry:

```
In [2]: d = defaultdict(list)

In [3]: d['c']
Out[3]: []

In [4]: d
Out[4]: defaultdict(list, {'c': []})
```

On a regular dictionary without the `setdefault`, the access attempt would throw a `KeyError`.